# Dompdf is writing on top of other html elements - Laravel 6 - PHP 8

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-6, dompdf

I'm writing a function to create and display a pdf file using **Dompdf** in a **Laravel 6** project using **PHP 8**. I tried with many tutorials and even the official documentation from GitHub for the normal [Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) version and it's [wrapper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) for Laravel. Here is my pdf generator function code:

```
private function generate_pdf(){
    $html = '
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Hello Dompdf</h1>
                <h2>MDF</h2>
            </body>
        </html>
    ';
    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);
    return $pdf->stream('welcome.pdf');
}
```

It works fine but here is the result of the function:

[image]

As you can see the elements are overlapping itself on top of each others. I looked for answers but I can't find anything related. Does somebody knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody have this problem again, I found a solution and it is the worst it can be:

```
private function generate_pdf(){
    $html = '
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Hello Dompdf</h1><br/><br/>
                <h2>MDF</h2>
            </body>
        </html>
    ';
    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);
    return $pdf->stream('welcome.pdf');
}
```

Just add 
 elements to every element in order to give the correct space. It is a nasty solution but it works.

Comment: use div tags & align your html components use div to divide html to sections will not have such issues then

Comment: Divs didn't work at all, it just made the block-type container and then draw it on top any other element (same case that I showed off). Alignment worked fine but it din't was too helpful to my task. The <br/> tag worked good... I wonder if that problem is happening only in my computer because I installed something wrong or there is a missing dependency, or there is someone else with the same problem .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is compatibility with `PHP 8` itself. I had the same issue and downgrading to PHP 7.4 has worked on my server. Not sure where the incompatibility may be, but immediately after updating to `PHP 8.0` `DOMPDF` stopped interpreting the HTML properly and started placing items on top of each other.